# Display a message while prompting for sudo password

Tags: command-line, sudo, password, customization

I had once seen a Ubuntu user use a sudo command in a terminal. Before he was prompted for a password he was shown the following message:

```
user1@linuxbox:~$ sudo apt-get update
Please do not run this command if you have not been granted sudo rights.
[sudo] password for user1:
```

I would like to display a similar message on my system when a user runs a sudo command. What must I edit/change to display a similar message when a user runs a sudo command on the terminal?

Answer (score 16):

See if your sudo supports `lecture_file` option

```
man sudoers | grep lecture_file
```

This is what man sudoers says in my case :

> lecture_file  Path to a file containing an alternate sudo lecture that will be  used in place of the standard lecture if the named file exists.  By default,  sudo uses a built-in lecture.

So, to change the text, add it to a file e.g `/etc/sudoers.lecture` and point to it from `/etc/sudoers` :

```
Defaults        lecture_file = /etc/sudoers.lecture
```

To display the lecture on every invocation of sudo also add the following to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults        lecture = always
```

Comment: Love how it's called "lecture." macOS gives you a lecture about abusing power when you first use sudo.

Comment: @sudo So does Ubuntu, at least in some situations.

Comment: @storm and how to turn it off iam using debian stretch and the sudo message is displayed by default i tryed using something like `lecture = off` but it's not recognized

Comment: @ABDELLATIFLAKEHAL : `lecture = never`

Answer (score 3):

Write a "wrapper script" around the `sudo` command.

Basically, you replace the standard `sudo` command with a script that contains a function called `sudo()`. This function first echoes your custom message, then calls the standard sudo command `/usr/bin/sudo`.

This script would be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo(){
        echo "This is a custom message."
        /usr/bin/sudo "$@"
}
```

You need to make sure the script is in the path of the user. [Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/unix-linux-bash-shell-script-wrapper-examples.html) (under "Putting it all together") is a good explanation of how to do this. Google "wrapper script" for other examples.